# Python- Iterating through a list using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a text file of dates in a list, like so:

```
values1 = ['1999-02-11', '1999-02-10', '1999-02-09', '1999-02-08', '1999-02-05',
           '1999-02-04', '1999-02-03', '1999-02-02', '1999-02-01', '1999-01-29',
           '1999-01-28', '1999-01-27', '1999-01-26', '1999-01-25', '1999-01-22',
           '1999-01-21', '1999-01-20', '1999-01-19', '1999-01-18', '1999-01-15',
           '1999-01-14', '1999-01-13', '1999-01-12', '1999-01-11', '1999-01-08',
           '1999-01-07', '1999-01-06', '1999-01-05', '1999-01-04']
```

and what I would like to do is iterate through each value, using this code to get the format using `datetime`. This should then allow me to plot this list of dates against a list of values.

I am trying to do this in the following couple of lines of code (this is only to get the list into the correct format, I have not yet got the code to plot the graph!)

```
for line in values1:
    datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Im not sure why?

ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

you said you are reading the list of dates from a file. May be one of the lines is have the word Date instead of the date value, or may be it is the header line.

the code which you have given works. Check the input values from the file

I have managed to get it working, thanks to the suggestion that the header within the text file would cause an error!

`values1=calues1[1::]
for line in values1:
    datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()`

Comment: For me this worked: `import datetime`
`for line in values1:`
`datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()`

Comment: Catch the exception and print the date value. You'll know if the date is _actually_ invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says

```
ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

you said you are reading the list of dates from a file.  May be one of the lines is have the word `Date` instead of the date value, or may be it is the header line.

the code which you have given works. Check the input values from the file

Comment: It could definitely be that, given that the first line would be "date"!
so if I iterated through, ignoring the first "date"" value, it would work?

Comment: @AlexWalton why don't you try it?

Comment: @AlexWalton you can try it.  That should work, if it is in the first line.  But what if it is somewhere in the data.  It would be better to handle the exception and print the value to help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me

```
from datetime import datetime

values1 = ['1999-02-11', '1999-02-10', '1999-02-09', '1999-02-08', '1999-02-05', '1999-02-04', '1999-02-03', '1999-02-02', '1999-02-01', '1999-01-29', '1999-01-28', '1999-01-27', '1999-01-26', '1999-01-25', '1999-01-22', '1999-01-21', '1999-01-20', '1999-01-19', '1999-01-18', '1999-01-15', '1999-01-14', '1999-01-13', '1999-01-12', '1999-01-11', '1999-01-08', '1999-01-07', '1999-01-06', '1999-01-05', '1999-01-04']

for line in values1:
    print datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Output

```
1999-02-11
1999-02-10
1999-02-09
1999-02-08
1999-02-05
1999-02-04
```

maybe you are problem is the import.

p.s. python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have datetime object imported from datetime module (the first line in the below snippet):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime 
>>> 
>>> values1 = ['1999-02-11', '1999-02-10', '1999-02-09', '1999-02-08', '1999-02-05', '1999-02-04', '1999-02-03', '1999-02-02', '1999-02-01', '1999-01-29', '1999-01-28', '1999-01-27', '1999-01-26', '1999-01-25', '1999-01-22', '1999-01-21', '1999-01-20', '1999-01-19', '1999-01-18', '1999-01-15', '1999-01-14', '1999-01-13', '1999-01-12', '1999-01-11', '1999-01-08', '1999-01-07', '1999-01-06', '1999-01-05', '1999-01-04']
>>> 
>>> for line in values1:
...     x = datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
...     print x
... 
1999-02-11
1999-02-10
1999-02-09
1999-02-08
1999-02-05
1999-02-04
1999-02-03
1999-02-02
1999-02-01
1999-01-29
1999-01-28
1999-01-27
1999-01-26
1999-01-25
1999-01-22
1999-01-21
1999-01-20
1999-01-19
1999-01-18
1999-01-15
1999-01-14
1999-01-13
1999-01-12
1999-01-11
1999-01-08
1999-01-07
1999-01-06
1999-01-05
1999-01-04
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your import. You must import the datetime module inside datetime.

Use either:

```
import datetime

for line in values1:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime

for line in values1:
    print datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

works both on python 2.7 and 3 (use print() instead for python 3).

Comment: Without (brief) explanation this answer is not very useful (±0).